# Can I set an infinite AutoPopDelay for a tooltip in a .NET Windows Forms window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I have a requirement to not have the standard .NET [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) tooltip automatcially hide - that is, I need them to remain visible until the mouse moves off the control that has the tooltip. I'd like to avoid having to use specific MouseEnter and MouseLeave events for all controls with a tooltip. I'm happy to hear about third-party solutions if they'd solve the problem.

Comment: Follow up - http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/10/55635.aspx

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254656/tooltips-with-infinite-timeout/2438612#2438612

Answer (score 14):

As it has been posted countless times and is known from the .NET Framework early days, you cannot set the AutoPopDelay time higher than an Int16.MaxValue (i.e. 32767) and have it working. Using the tooltip Show() method leads to the same result. Any value higher than 32767 leads the timer to be reset to 5000 ms.

Even an attempt to set the AutomaticDelay to a value that leads to an AutoPopDelay value higher than 32767 will cause the tooltip not to work. Furthermore, using the StopTimer() method doesn't yield any positive results.

The only way I was succesful in displaying a tooltip with infinite timeout was using the tooltip Show() method that passes the displayed position. `tooltip.Show(text, control, position)`. In conclusion, the tooltip control has the most bizarre behavior I have yet encountered in a control and the documentation about setting the delay times is quite misleading.

Answer (score 12):

I was searching for a solution to the problem

> 1. The popup baloon disappears too fast, not allowing me to read its content
> 2. The popup baloon does not appear again when hovering into that region.

I found in the forums the following answer, which does not solve Problem2, but lets me read the text for more than the time I need when I set its value to **32766** and is thus - in my opinion - a kind of 'work around':

> *Actually, I found out my problem was that I assigned a value higher than 32767 (32768 and higher will have an effect of 5 sec) really
>   weird, since AutoPopDelay is supposed to take an Integer (32 bit) as
>   parameter, and 32767 is really a signed 16 bit ...*

But I have to admit, it still sucks...

But setting it to **32000** (32 seconds) seems to work better. No clue why this is but maybe it helps someone.

Comment: There's a reason why you're experiencing int16 behavior. The WinForms Tooltip is actually a managed wrapper around the Win32 Tooltip. The Win32 version has a method called `TTM_SETDELAYTIME` which actually takes a 16 bit integer. I imagine that the developer for the .NET wrapper read the Win32 docs wrong and at this point there's not any business value in changing it and retesting as WinForms is dead.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760404(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @TheMuffinMan 'WinForms is dead'. Well that's a bold claim. What exactly do you propose is replacing them? Certainly not Win8 Apps. WPF? Are Tooltips more functional there?

Comment: @Dan Obviously WPF has replaced it.

Answer (score 3):

In my application, the tooltip text has to update every 10 seconds. What works for me is to deactivate and activate the tooltip every time this text is updated. When I set the AutoPopDelay to more than 10 seconds, the tooltip will effectively stay forever. So you might use a timer to repeatedly activate and deactivate the tooltip:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    toolTip1.Active = false;
    toolTip1.Active = true;
}
```

To minimize the flicker that happens on reactivating the tooltip, set the InitialDelay to 1. When you set the AutoPopDelay to 30000 and the timer interval also to 30000 you'll see a very short flicker only once every 30 seconds. For my application this short flicker is acceptable. Btw, don't forget to turn on the timer! (At first I thought it didn't work, until I discovered I forgot to turn on the timer ;-))

Of course this is a cure for the symptoms and not an elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try `myToolTip.ReshowDelay = 0`.

You just reshow the tooltip immediately after its delay expires. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be the answer you want to hear... Roll your own. I once had scenario where I wanted to simulate the new Office's ribbonbar tooltip behavour for shortcut keyboard commands and I found that the standard tooltip API is just too limited.

Make a small, simple and border-less form instance for every control that you need a tooltip for. Then show and hide them non-modally as you do a mouse-enter or -leave event. Have the constructor for this window receive the UI control instance and let it query the control for it's events so that it can attach itself to the mouse-enter and -leave events, so that you wouldn't have to wire them up manually.

Comment: Was really hoping that wasn't the answer.  I think if I had to do this I'd have one form (or even label) that I would float over the top using MouseEnter/Leave and populate with the appropriate text at runtime.  Was hoping to avoid it ... but may not be able to.

Answer (score 1):

So, I ended up de-activating the tooltip, but I am still using it to hold the text for the tooltip, because it neatly adds itself to all the controls. I made my own panel and label inside it for the tooltip and dynamically positioned, made visible and populated the text on the mouse enter and mouse leave events of all the controls.

I also wrote a recursive function to add the mouse events to each label control (the only ones I have tooltips on), so I didn't have to manually to it and won't have to remember to do it when I add a new label. New developers on the project may not ever realise that the tooltip control is not actually rendering the tips.

Why a label in a panel? - so really big tooltips can scroll - although this is still not working nicely.

It is not real pretty, and I am still looking for a good answer if you've got on (or a critique of the method I've employed).

I came across http://www.binarymission.co.uk/, but their tooltip did not seem to render properly in my .NET 3.5 application. I am still talking to them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to cure the symptoms and not the cause of your problem.

You are trying to force a ToolTip to be something different from a ToolTip. A tooltip is, by definition, "a small "hover box" with information about the item being hovered over".

If the user can't read what the tooltip is trying to suggest in 30 seconds, then it isn't really a "tip" but an entire chapter from the help file. Put lengthy instructions into the Manual and do not attempt to force it into a ToolTip that stays open forever.

Comment: Why do so many answers here take the form of "You shouldn't be doing what you're trying to do"? The poster wants an answer, not a judgment.

Comment: Because most don't realize it's wrong, why it is, and what the consequences to code, design, and usability pains being created.

Comment: @JohnArlen Have you considered all of the use cases? What if you have a form that when you focus on a field you want to display a tool tip that shows as long as the field is focused, or perhaps you have a question mark icon to the right of your field and want it to show as long as the user is hovered over it? These types of situations are elegantly used all over the web.

Answer (score 1):

In my limited experience, I have found that setting the showAlways property to true has the side effect of making the tip display "infinitely" (until the cursor exits the control). This is not what the documentation says it will do, but that's what I have experienced. (However, I am using the Janus Supertip component, and it's possible that affects the behavior).

Answer (score -1):

Set the ToolTipService.ShowDuration attached property to int.MaxValue:

```
<Button 
  Height="23" Width="75"
  Content="Click Me" 
  ToolTip="My ToolTip" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="2147483647" 
/>
```

Comment: I need this for a desktop application, so there is no markup (and no property of the ToolTip called "ShowDuration".

Comment: Sorry, it seems that I didn't pay attention to the winform part! This is for WPF.

Comment: According to [jimi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805430/can-i-set-an-infinite-autopopdelay-for-a-tooltip-in-a-net-windows-forms-window/10143251#10143251) this would reset it to 5000 ms.

Answer (score -1):

The `ToolTip.StopTimer` method might help. From MSDN:

> The ToolTip class has an internal timer that it uses to set the display duration for ToolTips. The duration associated with this timer is set through the AutoPopDelay property. **The StopTimer method will stop this internal timer, causing any displayed ToolTip to be shown modally until the Hide method is called**, or the parent form is minimized, hidden, or closed.

Comment: I can't see a method on the ToolTip for StopTimer.  This is for a windows form desktop application.  Do you have the MSDN refrence?

Comment: assume you mean this page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.stoptimer.aspx
This seems to be a private method so I'm not sure how I can execute it...?  Do I then have to manage the Hide call from the MouseLeave event for each control?

Comment: It's protected, so I think you can subclass the ToolTip control, handle the Popup event, and call this method from there.