# Windows Forms toolTip forever using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

How do I set a toolTip that doesn't go away as long as you're hovering on the control?

I tried setting the "AutoPopDelay" to 999999, but the tooltip disappears after 15 seconds.

Or, is there another way to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From MSDN:

> There are multiple delay values that
>   you can set for a Windows Forms
>   ToolTip  component. The unit of
>   measure for all these properties is
>   milliseconds. The InitialDelay
>   property determines how long the user
>   must point at the associated control
>   for the ToolTip  string  to appear.
>   The ReshowDelay property sets the
>   number of milliseconds it takes for
>   subsequent ToolTip strings  to appear
>   as the mouse moves from one
>   ToolTip-associated control to another.
>   The AutoPopDelay property determines
>   the length of time the ToolTip  string
>   is shown. You can set these values
>   individually, or by setting the value
>   of the AutomaticDelay property; the
>   other delay properties are set based
>   on the value assigned to the
>   AutomaticDelay property. For example,
>   when AutomaticDelay is set to a value
>   N, InitialDelay is set to N,
>   ReshowDelay is set to the value of
>   AutomaticDelay divided by five (or
>   N/5), and AutoPopDelay is set to a
>   value that is five times the value of
>   the AutomaticDelay property (or 5N).

For more information on this subject, look here:

- [ToolTip Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.aspx)
- [Make tooltips remain visible for a very long time in Visual Basic .NET](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_permanent_tooltip.html)
- Stack Overflow question *[Can I set an infinite AutoPopDelay for a tooltip in a .NET Windows Forms window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805430/can-i-set-an-infinite-autopopdelay-for-a-tooltip-in-a-net-winform)*
- [Tooltips with infinite timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254656/tooltips-with-infinite-timeout/2438612#2438612)

Comment: ReshowDelay doesn't work, because when the tooltip disappears, you have to hover on another tooltipped control for the tooltip to appear again. Very useless. and even worse, if you only have one tooltipped control, you can't have the tooltip to pop up after its timer is done

Comment: If *ReshowDelay* allegdedly doesn't work, then why have you marked it as the answer? Was the answer in one of the other links?

Comment: hmmm I still have to explore the other answers to see one that fits me. will take time. but for now, I wanted to be nice and thank the guy for his time. is that a problem?

Comment: This answer is ridiculous. You just googled his question and linked documentation. Anyone can do that. In other words your answer doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Perhaps mentioning the 32.767 seconds limit would be in order (due to the underlying signed 16-bit value in a Windows API function) - if it is real.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

> AutoPopDelay = 32767 MSDN states this is Int32, but anything over 32767 will fail.
>
> InitialDelay = 200
>
> ReshowDelay = 200

This should make the tooltip be shown for as long as possible.
I hope it helped.