# Change ToolTip Timeout for all tooltips in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm writing my solution in Microsoft Visual C# Express 2010.

I've browsed other topics so far and all I've found are ways to change the timeout of individual tooptips.

I'd like all my tooltips to remain open as long as the mouse is over the control for all my existing tooltips.

Is there a way to change the default setting? Or maybe I'll have to loop through each control, which seems inefficient.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530841/c-sharp-winforms-tooltip-forever

Comment: Still focuses on the individual tooltip, whereas I need a global solution.

Comment: Technically you should only need one Tooltip.  You set its properties such as timeout, and then you tell it which tooltip text to show on each control either in the designer or with the SetTooltip function.  The only time you have multiple tooltips is if you have one in each scope, like in each Form or custom UserControl.

Comment: How many forms and custom controls do you have?  If you have a form that contains even 100 controls, that should still only require one ToolTip object.  If you have 5 forms, then you need 5 tooltips.  Unless you have dozens of forms in your project it shouldn't take too long to set the properties of each.

Comment: Ah ok I see. My understanding was wrong. 
/*Set ToolTip Timeout*/
toolTip1.AutomaticDelay = 1000; 
completed the need. Thanks. I you place your explanation as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The default delays are a multiple of the mouse double-click time.  Changing that setting has a system-wide effect, you cannot reasonably do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like yourToolTip.AutomaticDelay is the property you are looking for.  The default is 500 ms, but you could set it to be really long to keep it open.

You can get more information on [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network), *[ToolTip.AutomaticDelay Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.automaticdelay.aspx)*.

Other properties of AutomaticDelay are AutoPopDelay, InitialDelay, and ReshowDelay.