# Is it possible to dynamically change tooltip text in C# without changing the behavior of the tooltip?

Tags: c#, tooltip

I have a ToolTip control I am using to display text from a control when the control's size is too small to display all the text. In general, this works fine, but the control's text updates frequently based on external events making the tooltip's text stale. If possible, I would like to be able to update the tooltip's text to match the control's text without changing the tooltip's behavior. By this, I mean change the tooltip's text without changing the timing of when the tooltip is displayed and hidden.

I have tried using `SetToolTip`, but this causes the tooltip to appear immediately if the control's text changes while the mouse is hovering over the control rather than waiting the 500ms delay setting. Also, updating the text in this manner keeps the tooltip from ever timing out.

Comment: `toolTip1.Active = false` will deactivate ToolTip. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496836/4123703)

Comment: Yes. If the Control has a `TextChanged` event of sort, you can add to the handler: `if ([ToolTip].Active) { [ToolTip].Show([Control].Text, [Control]); }`. The ToolTip settings are unchanged. It's better if you have an OwnerDrawn ToolTip.

Comment: My goal is for the tooltip to behave the same as if it had static text, but with dynamic text. Using an OwnerDrawn toolTip would only be useful if I could extract the handle to the control showing the tooltip text to change it dynamically, bypassing the toolTip.SetToolTip function.